# How to get the exit status of htpasswd?

Tags: bash, shell, centos, .htpasswd

I am working on a shell script to ease htpasswd management for accounts.

I am trying to check if the htpasswd was created properly using the expected exit status from the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html)

this is what I have so far:

Existing htpasswd:

```
local _result=$(htpasswd "${HTPASSWD_LOCATION}" "${_htpasswdLogin}")
```

New htpasswd:

```
local _result=$(htpasswd -c "${HTPASSWD_LOCATION}" "${_htpasswdLogin}")
```

For some reason, this is being successful but I am not able to capture the exit status.

This is my check:

```
if [ "${_result}" = "0" ]; then
    echo "User successfully added to the .htpasswd file"
else
    echo "Failed to add the user to .htpasswd file"
fi
```

Is there a better method to get the exit status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
if htpasswd -c "${HTPASSWD_LOCATION}" "${_htpasswdLogin}"; then
    echo "User successfully added to the .htpasswd file"
else
    echo "Failed to add the user to .htpasswd file"
fi
```

Comment: I tired using this method but it gives me this error: `/usr/bin/manageAccount: line 735: [: too many arguments` I think this may be due to me not sending the password as I want this to remain a prompt. Line 735: `if [ htpasswd -c "${HTPASSWD_LOCATION}" "${_htpasswdLogin}" ]; then`

Comment: No if you notice I didn't have `[ and ]` in if condition.

Comment: I realized i left the brackets in. Removing them solved the issue. Thanks! Will accept in 2 mins as it won't allow me until then